# PrimeFaces deleting a row from DataTable absurd error

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, managed-bean

I'm working with a DataTable component, and my very straightforward goal is to delete a row using an inline command button. This is the code for the dataTable component.

```
        <p:dataTable rowKey="#{dobavljac.dobavljacID}" value="#{dobavljacMB.vratiDobavljace()}" var="dobavljac" >
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">ID</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{dobavljac.dobavljacID}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Naziv</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{dobavljac.naziv}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Adresa</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{dobavljac.adresa}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column colspan="2" style="text-align: center">
                <f:facet name="header">Operacija</f:facet>
                <p:commandButton id="viewButton" style="height: 35px" value="Delete" action="#{dobavljacMB.obrisi(dobavljac)}" ajax="false"/>          
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
```

"dobavljac" is the entity I need to delete using **action="#{dobavljacMB.obrisi(dobavljac)}"**

The managed bean class that has the deleting function "obrisi" is as follows:

```
/**
 * Creates a new instance of DobavljacMB
 */
private Dobavljac tekuci;

public Dobavljac getTekuci() {
    return tekuci;
}

public void setTekuci(Dobavljac tekuci) {
    this.tekuci = tekuci;
}



public DobavljacMB() {
}

public String prikazDobavljaca() {

    System.out.println("Prikaz dobavljaca");
    // System.out.println("podaci su:"+tekuciKorisnik.getKorisnickoIme());



    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Ne postoji korisnik sa tim korisnickim imenom i sifrom!", ""));
    return null;
}

public List<Dobavljac> vratiDobavljace() {

    return KonekcijaDB.vratiInstancu().vratiDobavljace();

}

public String obrisi(Dobavljac d){
    try {
        System.out.println("obrisi");
        KonekcijaDB.vratiInstancu().obrisi(d);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Dobavljac obrisan", ""));
        return "prikazDobavljaca.xhtml";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Greska pri brisanju", ""));
        return "prikazDobavljaca.xhtml";
    }


    }
```

The Dobavljac class is a simple POJO class, generated by the IDE, so no need to post it. The problem is that when the method is called, it throws a 
**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert model.Dobavljac[ dobavljacID=66 ] of type class model.Dobavljac to class model.Dobavljac** which is pretty absurd, since the object passed is the same as the one in the MB method "obrisi(Dobavljac d)". 
Of course, the object is never deleted from the DB, since the method is not invoked. My thoughts are that it's a PrimeFaces problem, and not one of the JSF.

I've found examples that are very similar to this, and found that no one had this kind of problem (conversion between same classes), and don't need to implement a converter.

I'm not sure if I need to add some more info to the question, and I'd be most thankful for an answer. It is very annoying. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert model.Dobavljac[ dobavljacID=66 ]
>       of type class model.Dobavljac to class model.Dobavljac
> ```

The webapp's runtime classpath is dirty. There are multiple class file definitions of the `model.Dobavljac` class, each loaded by a different `ClassLoader`. The webapp's runtime classpath covers by default all class files in `/WEB-INF/classes`, all JAR files `/WEB-INF/lib`, all JAR files in server's `/lib`, all JAR files in JRE's `/lib` and `/lib/ext`. The server can have other folders added via specific configuration settings. How and which exactly depends on the server's make/version which you didn't tell anything about.

Cleanup the runtime classpath and get rid of the duplicate class file definiton (either the just standalone `.class` file, or the JAR file containing the offending `.class` file). After a rebuild/redeploy/restart this problem should disappear.

Comment: Thank you for the super quick response! I double-checked all my folders/packages for double class entries, and it wasn't the case. I forgot to mention that I am using GlassFish 3+ which I configured only to use specific database connection, no extra folders. The problem (finally) went away after several rebuild, deploy, undeploy operations. The exception I had wasn't easy to understand. Also, I have a quick question, being a beginner at this: what is the best practice for "Running", deploying, building etc in NetBeans when changing code, or adding new libs, resources..? Thanks again!

Comment: Apparently it was somewhere in Netbeans or Glassfish cache. Sorry, I can't speak for Netbeans, I just use Eclipse (with JRebel to speed up hotdeployment).

Comment: @BorkoS you can use hot-deployment property of Netbeans for seeing the changes in code in browser. To do that right click on your netbeans project and select properties. From properties pane choose Compile menu which is under Build menu. From this menu choose "For both application and test execution" for the attribute "Compile on Save". This will enable netbeans to deploy your changes to glassfish server after your each save.

Comment: @cubbuk Thanks for the suggestion, I'm already using that option. Apparently, I have a bad habit of hitting "Run" on the whole project, which I think transfers everything to server, not just the difference. I just recently started working with JavaEE, having moved from regular desktop applications.

Comment: You are welcome =) And be careful about javascript files and css files during the development. Because when you make a change to those files sometimes you need to clean the cache of the browser to see the changes which turns in an annoying situation when you need to deal with javascript.

Comment: Every kind of helpful information is welcome, I'll keep that in mind. :)